# selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -userExtensions command line argument throwing error

Tags: selenium-rc

I was trying to execute selenium ide test suite with the following commandline.

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -userExtensions: "C:\Selenium\user-extensions.js" -htmlSuite "*iexplore" "http://google.com" "C:\Selenium\3" "C:\Selenium\results1.html"

I observed that, without -userExtensions argument above command executes perfectly fine but when i added -userExtensions argument it threw following error,

11:13:39.734 WARN - Embedded iexplore seems to have ended on its own (did we kil
l the real browser???)
Tests failed, see result file for details: C:\Selenium\results1.html

On the other hand if I change the browser to firefox then script stuck at following

11:20:52.296 INFO - Checking Resource aliases.

What is possibly going wrong with the -userExtensions argument.

Help on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. It turned out I had extensions in there that was incompatible with selenium server. Removing those extensions fixed the issue.